# Micronaut generic GRPC proxy

Tags: java, proxy, grpc, micronaut

In the process of replacing an old legacy service by a new one we want to temporarily forward the requests reaching the new service to the legacy one. For HTTP requests we achieve this with a custom [HttpFilter](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/filter/HttpFilter.html):

```
@Filter("/**/legacy-service/**")
public class LegacyHttpProxyFilter implements HttpFilter {

  @Inject
  @Named("legacy-http-client")
  private ProxyHttpClient httpClient;

  @Override
  public Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, FilterChain chain) {
    return httpClient.proxy(request);
  }
}
```

The analogous approach for GRPC would be something similar to this with a [ServerInterceptor](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerInterceptor.html):

```
@Singleton
public class LegacyGrpcProxyInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

  @Inject
  @Named("legacy-grpc-client")
  MyLegacyServiceGrpc.MyLegacyServiceStub legacyServiceStub;

  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    return null; // How to handle GRPC requests in a generic way?
  }
}
```

The difference is that with a *ProxyHttpClient* we can forward any HTTP request, while this doesn't seem to be possible with *MyLegacyServiceStub* GRPC stub. It looks like the right approach is to implement a custom [ServerCallHandler](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerCallHandler.html) but I don't really see how, any example would be highly appreciated.

**How can I forward any incoming GRPC request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [such an example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/grpcproxy/GrpcProxy.java) in grpc-java.

You are right that the core of it should be to implement a `ServerCallHandler`. You will also need a `MethodDescriptor` and to package them together into a `ServerMethodDefinition`.

The example uses a fallback `HandlerRegistry` to proxy all methods, but if you only need static proxying you could create a `ServerServiceDefinition` (essentially a set of `ServerMethodDefinitions` for one service) for each service you want proxied and add it to the `ServerBuilder` as normal: `serverBuilder.addService()`.

The rest of the example is gluing the client and server calls together, with proper flow control for streaming RPCs.